# Backbone: Check if model's attributes changed or at previous state

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I've a scenario where a user can update his/her profile. By default, the **SAVE** button is disabled and only gets enabled when a user changes any field.

He has something like this:

[image]

Now if a user changes his/her first/last name, as:

[image]

The **SAVE** button is enabled and I maintain a status for any field change. What I'm doing here is:

```
firstNameChanged: function(){
            this.status = this.model.hasChanged("firstName");
            this.model.set("firstName",  this.$('#firstName').val());
        },
lastNameChanged: function(){
            this.status = this.model.hasChanged("lastName");
            this.model.set("lastName",  this.$('#lastName').val());
        }
```

And I handle the model change scenario as:

```
this.model.on('change', this.enableSaveButton, this);
```

This works fine until the user changes his/her First/Last name, but when a user changes his/her names back to previous one, I want to **DISABLE** the **SAVE** button, that in my case I'm confused on how to go about it. Please suggest the right way to go about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to save the original names somewhere and compare any changes to them. Backbone can't do anything automatic for you here; one can imagine a user making hundreds of changes before returning to the original value.

Comment: @StephenThomas, I got that working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How are you binding the form with the model..? Do you have two way binding..? When/How does the model gets updated..?